# How common are missile defense systems on civil airplanes?

Tags: airliner

I've just stumbled upon [Why don't El Al 747's stay at the gates at JFK?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/49834/why-dont-el-al-747s-stay-at-the-gates-at-jfk) in the hot topics.
I kind of get why El Al decided to put missile defense systems in their planes but I was wondering: How common is this? Are there other airlines who do this?

Comment: Obligatory:  I could tell you but then I'd have to kill you.

Comment: The day my inabillity to properly read a Wikipedia article made it to over 2k views...

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It's far from being common. The following carriers use missile defense on all or part of their fleet:

- El Al
- Israir and Arkia "can be assumed" to use the laser-type from Elbit ([flightglobal.com](https://www.flightglobal.com/news/articles/el-al-and-other-carriers-in-line-for-laser-based-ant-328846/), 2009).

> While Elbit has not identified any of the carriers likely to receive the equipment, a source familiar with the agreement says "it can be assumed" that all three major Israeli airlines - El Al, Israir and Arkia - are in line to be fitted.

- FedEx uses Northrop Grumman Guardian ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northrop_Grumman_Guardian#Deployment)).

Missile defense systems are also reportedly installed on some VIP business jets.

---

Further reading:

- [Flight Guard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_Guard)
- [Directional Infrared Counter Measures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directional_Infrared_Counter_Measures)
- [Civil Aircraft Missile Protection System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Civil_Aircraft_Missile_Protection_System)

Related: [How does the Guardian counter-MANPADS system work?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/8055/14897)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75146/discussion-on-answer-by-ymb1-how-common-are-missile-defense-systems-on-civil-air).

Comment: If I'm not mistaken Fedex only equips a few aircraft which are used to fly into 'unsafe airspace' under their military charters. Not all aircraft are equipped.