# Do El Al Israel aircraft have Chaff/Flare dispensers and Radar Warning Receivers?

Tags: airliner, missiles

I have heard that El Al Israel aircraft have missile warning systems and lasers to stop anti-aircraft weapons. Do El Al Israel aircraft have chaff/flare dispensers and [Radar Warning Receiver (RWR)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radar_warning_receiver) too?

Comment: Related: [Why don't El Al 747's stay at the gates at JFK?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/49834/why-dont-el-al-747s-stay-at-the-gates-at-jfk) and [How common are missile defense systems on civil airplanes?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/49855/how-common-are-missile-defense-systems-on-civil-airplanes)

Answer (score 1):

From what I could find, they used to use a Doppler radar to detect a missile and launch flares to counter it in a system called Flight Guard but it was deemed too dangerous and a fire hazard so they replaced it with a new system. What they have instead now is a MAWS (Missile Approach Warning System) that is designed to detect missile launches very early on with methods such as an IR camera and it seems to use some kind of a laser to counter the missile by messing with its sensor and making it go off course. This system is called C-MUSIC

Here is a video with some... crusty CGI that gives a basic demonstration of how it works

Comment: "Climb flight level 3000" - wow, thats some altitude! You would think that the script of even a faked aviation video would have some clue about aviation terminology :D

Comment: I mean climbing to flight level 3000 would be a pretty effective way to avoid SAMs!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know if a specific plane has missile countermeasures, you could take a look at the rear of the plane. If there is an active countermeasure installed, you should be able to see a "box" mounted under the plane (pic attached).

FedEx tried to propose for the installation of countermeasures but the FAA halted the certification process in Jan 22 [[Reuters]](https://www.reuters.com/business/aerospace-defense/us-faa-halts-review-fedex-proposal-install-a321-laser-based-missile-defense-2022-01-18/)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

EL AL are reported the C-Music IR counter measures system. It is not flares, but instead an IR strobe to counter the simple IR seeker heads in man portable IR missles.

Comment: Is there a link available to confirm what you posted? I agree that a jammer or DIRCM would seem to make better sense than flares, given the available technology.